# How to render all data in relation in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am new in this situation, I wan't to get value of "**otmain_many_otline**" but I don't know how to get it, I think I should put it in array cause when I use this 
$list->otmain_many_otline[0]->purpose I only get first data. My problem is I don't know the syntax how to render all data?

**View**

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
 <thead>
  <th>Purpose</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($ot_list as $list)
   <tr>
    <td>        
       {{$list->otmain_many_otline[0]->purpose}}
    </td>
   </tr>
  @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Model**

```
class OTMain extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ot_main';
    public function otmain_many_otline(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\OTline', 'ot_main_id','id');
       }

}

class OTLine extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ot_line';
    public function otline_belong_otmain(){
          return $this->hasOne('App\OTMain', 'ot_main_id');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
 $ot_list = OTMain::whereIn('created_by', $requestor_list)
     ->with('otmain_many_otline')
     ->where('ot_status', 1)
     ->get();
 dd($ot_list);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: So do you want to retrieve all value from $list->otmain_many_otline and show them ? If yes just use another foreach there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `otmain_many_otline` relation is `hasMany` meaning that it will return you collection of related objects. Make sure to read [official documentation on them](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections).

If you need to get first related object then use method `first()`. In your case:

```php
@foreach($ot_list as $list)
    <tr>
        <td>        
            {{ $list->otmain_many_otline->first()->purpose }}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

If you need to render all related objects you can also just iterate through `omain_many_otline` with another `@foreach`:

```php
...
<td>
    @foreach ($list->otmain_many_otline as $otline)
        <p>{{ $otline->purpose }}</p>
    @endforeach
</td>
...
```

Comment: @MathewMagante extended my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
@foreach($ot_list as $list)
<tr>
 <td>
    @foreach($list->otmain_many_otline as $ot) // foreach for $otmain_many_otline       
     {{$ot->purpose}} , &nbsp;
    @endforeach
 </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```